# Changing values when converting column type to numeric

Tags: r

I have a data file with the format from above.
I loaded it into R, and tried to plot a histogram with the values from the dist column and I have got the error "x must be numeric".Therefore I tried to change the format.

```
> head(data)

    V1        V2
1 type gene_dist
2    A     64667
3    A     76486
4    A     97416
5    A     30876
6    A     88018

> summary(data)
    V1            V2     
 A   : 67   100    :  1  
 B   :122   100906 :  1  
 type:  1   102349 :  1  
            1033   :  1  
            10544  :  1  
            10745  :  1  
            (Other):184
```

I tried to set the format for the column using `sapply` but the values are changed:

```
> data[,2]<-sapply(data[,2],as.numeric)

> head(data)
    V1  V2
1 type 190
2    A 146
3    A 166
4    A 189

summary(data)
    V1            V2        
 A   : 67   Min.   :  1.00  
 B   :122   1st Qu.: 48.25  
 type:  1   Median : 95.50  
            Mean   : 95.50  
            3rd Qu.:142.75  
            Max.   :190.00
```

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: can you paste the output of `dput(data)` so that we can reproduce your results. My suspicion is that you are converting a `factor` to `numeric` directly, which is causing the problem. Try replacing it with `function(x) as.character(as.numeric(x))` and see if that works

Comment: @ Ramnath - problem solved with as.numeric(as.character(x))

Comment: It looks like R is classing your columns as factors because you're reading the header as a row entry. Setting `header = T` in your `read.table()` call should fix this.

Comment: @ricardh - I removed the columns from the text file and added them manually, probably not the most elegant way...but it works.
colnames(chip_data)<-c("type","gene_dist")

Answer (score 68, accepted):

It looks like your second column is a factor. You need to use `as.character` before `as.numeric`. This is because factors are stored internally as integers with a table to give the factor level labels. Just using `as.numeric` will only give the internal integer codes. There is no need to use `sapply` since these functions are vectorized.

```
data[,2] <- as.numeric(as.character(data[,2]))
```

It is likely that the column is a factor because there are some non-numeric characters in some of the entries. Any such entries will be converted to `NA` with the appropriate warning, but you may want to investigate this in your raw data.

As a side note, `data` is a poor (though not invalid) choice for a variable name since there is a base function of the same name.

Comment: @ James : It worked. Thanks and I will consider your observation.

Comment: @Andra I can see now that your question is formatted a little better that one reason that it is a factor is that the column names are included in the data. You might want to add a `header=TRUE` argument to the command you read the data in with.

Comment: @James- I will remember that.  - I removed the columns from the text file and added them manually, probably not the most elegant way...but it works. colnames(chip_data)<-c("type","gene_dist")

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/q/3418128/210673: `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` is an alternate method that is slightly more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but as I found, the root cause was different, and so I share this as an answer but not a comment.

```
df <- read.table(doc.csv, header = TRUE, sep = ",", dec = ".")
df$value

# Results in
[1]  2254    1873    2201    2147    2456    1785

# So..
as.numeric(df$value)
[1] 26 14 22 20 32 11
```

In my case, the reason was that there were spaces with the values in the original csv document. Removing the spaces fixed the issue.

**From the dput(df)**

```
" 1178  ", " 1222  ", " 1223  ", " 1314  ", " 1462  ",
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue for a matrix containing 'list' values, when an object `data` was read in from read.csv.  `as.character()` does not work here, and `as.numeric()` and `data.matrix()`  changed the values in the matrix. Instead you need to use the following:

`matrix_numeric[1:m,1:n] <- as.numeric(as.matrix(data[1:m,1:n]))`

First converting to a character then to a double. For matrix dimensions data[m,n]. (you need to create the object matrix_numeric first before assigning values...  `matrix_numeric <- matrix(0,m,n)` )

For a vector `vec1` in list format, I use the following:

`out1 <- as.numeric(unlist(vec1));`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably much better to fix it when reading the file than by using `as.numeric()` or `as.character()`. When reading your file, make sure to have:

- `header=TRUE` if first row is header
- `NA` and not `Na` or `NaN` (ctrl+H and replace by NA in your datafile)
- no other character strings in your numeric columns

Then R will automatically consider them as numeric.