# Reshape2: dcast() returning - ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors

Tags: r, reshape2, dcast

dataset: I will call it CAR

```
Car_Type | Cyl | Miles | State | Color | Tires

.....
```

My data can have `NULL` for `Miles`

I'm trying to run `dcast()` on a data set that shows all variables as numeric. `sapply(CAR, mode))`.

```
> sapply(CAR, mode)
> CAR     Cyl    Miles      State       Color     Tires
>    "numeric"     "numeric"     "numeric"     "numeric"     "numeric"     "numeric"
```

When I run the following code, I get 0 and 1 for the values and looks like it's returning the number of times Miles is not `NULL`:

```
Pivot <- dcast(CAR, Car_Type ~ Cyl, value.var = "Miles")
```

When I try to run the following to get the sum of Miles

```
Pivot <- dcast(CAR, Car_Type ~ Cyl, value.var = "Miles", fun.aggregate = sum)
```

I get the following error:

> ‘sum’ not meaningful for factors

I tried `transform(CAR, Miles = as.numeric(Miles))`, but get the same error.

What am I missing here to be able to find the sum of miles while "pivoting" `Car_Type` and `Cyl` and aggregate the sum of miles? Is the `NULL` values causing the error? I thought `NULL` wasn't an issue for `dcast` aggregations.

Comment: Please [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R post that folks can answer easily. It looks like you have an issue with data types, but without seeing your actual data, the best we can do is guess

Comment: Thanks @camille. I tried randomizing a spinet, but I don't think I have enough "rep" to post it. The actual data set contains sensitive data, so I can't post it to get an error. I will try to give a better format in the future.

Comment: I thought it was data types as well, but the `Miles` variable is showing numeric per `sapply()`?

Comment: If you can't post the actual data, you can edit your post to include dummy data or something else to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

I ate lunch and thought about a few things and figured it out. It seems that my variable `Miles` was a factor even though `sapply()` was returning "numeric". I ran the following:

```
is.numeric(CAR$Miles)
[1] FALSE
```

I then converted the factor to a numeric by running (more on this here: [Changing values when converting column type to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328771/changing-values-when-converting-column-type-to-numeric):

```
CAR$Miles2 <- as.numeric(as.character(CAR$Miles))
```

After the change from a factor to numeric, I was able to successfully run my line:

```
Pivot <- dcast(CAR, Car_Type ~ Cyl, value.var = "Miles2", fun.aggregate = sum, na.rm=TRUE)
```