# Why does changing the class of a column on a data frame alter the values?

Tags: r

I want to change the class of the column of a data frame so that I can correlate values and create graphs. However, when I use the code below, the values change.
The original class of "Depth" is factor and I want to change it to numeric.
Could anybody explain to me why this happens and if it is posible to change the class without having this problem?

## Original Data frame (Site.copy):

```
Plot     Depth
1         1.29
2         0.82
3         1.21
4         3.16
5         12.64
```

Site.copy$Depth<-as.numeric(as.character(Site.copy$Depth))

## Changed Site.copy:

```
Plot     Depth
1         1.290000e+00
2         8.200000e+01
3         1.210000e+00
4         3.160000e+00
5         1.264000e+01
```

Comment: try ``as.numeric(as.character)`` Factors can create some problems.

Comment: Factors are stored as numbers in r. You could probably do `as.numeric(Site.Copy$Depth))`

Comment: @yfa that will likely introduce errors, since the numbers of a factor correspond to their *order*, not anything to do with their *value*. See the link in the posted answer

Comment: @camille The author seems to have changed the question a few times. In the original she didn't make clear the class of the column. It seemed, the author changed a character vector to a factor to then make a numeric. I completely agree with the posted answer

Answer (score 0):

try - this has to do with converting factors to numbers

```
as.numeric(as.character(Site.copy$Depth))
```

see this explanation: [Changing values when converting column type to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328771/changing-values-when-converting-column-type-to-numeric)

R defaults to factors in many cases.  You can always check `sapply( x , class)`