# Numeric values depending of apply family applied, R

Tags: r, casting, apply

I've a table with some numeric and character cols, some are factors and other integers.

```
>additional.metadata
      sample_id patient_id condition SOM test
1387          1          1       CTL  22    1
7588          1          1       CTL  35    2
7429          1          1       CTL  23    3
7600          1          1       CTL  35    4
```

I'm trying to convert the entire table to a matrix and, depending of `apply` option used (i.e. `apply` vs `sapply`), some values from *$SOM* changes. Here's an example:

```
> apply(additional.metadata, 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.factor(x)))
     sample_id patient_id condition SOM test
[1,]         1          1         1   2    1
[2,]         1          1         1   4    2
[3,]         1          1         1   3    3
[4,]         1          1         1   4    4
[5,]         1          1         1   1    5
[6,]         1          1         1   3    6
> sapply(additional.metadata, function(x) as.numeric(as.factor(x)))
     sample_id patient_id condition SOM test
[1,]         1          1         1  22    1
[2,]         1          1         1  35    2
[3,]         1          1         1  23    3
[4,]         1          1         1  35    4
[5,]         1          1         1  11    5
[6,]         1          1         1  23    6
```

Someone knows what I'm missing/misunderstanding, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: (This is a common question on SO.) `apply` always converts it first argument to a `matrix`. When there are any `character` columns, **everything** becomes `character`, period. Typically you'd use `apply` on a subset of columns, e.g., `apply(x[,c(1:3,5)], 2, ...)`, in order to only use numeric columns you truly need. If you want help with your frame (as a mix of `numeric`, `factor`, and `character`), then you *must* provide usable data in the form of `dput(head(x))`; console output is ambiguous.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this matrix conversion of `apply`, very useful.

Comment: What is your intended output?

Comment: I'd like to transform my _$SOM_ col in numeric but keeping its original numeric values, without re-coding them (that's why I asked). Thanks

Comment: jgarces, I don't say it without reason: the use of `dput` in giving us sample data provides ***unambiguous*** data. What you have provided is not clear, because R's console output does not differentiate between `integer`, whole `numeric`, `factor`, and numeric-looking `character`. So we cannot help you unless you provide something that is actually representative of what you have. So again, please provide data by giving us the output from `dput(head(additional.metadata))`.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the changes are happening because of `as.numeric(as.factor(x))`.

To make sure your value stay as intended you need to convert to `character` or skip the factor stage at all.

Use `as.numeric(as.character(as.factor(x)))` or `as.numeric(as.character(x))` instead.

An explanation of why you need to do this can be foudn on the top answer of this question:

[Changing values when converting column type to numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328771/changing-values-when-converting-column-type-to-numeric)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if I use `as.numeric(as.character(x))` because character cols, some values are transformed incorrectly to NAs.